# Custom templates folder

Tags: templates

Set the Custom Template Directory and created 3 templates, but CiviCRM loads standard templates. What did I do wrong?

**Settings in WordPress:**

[image: settings]

**Folder:**

[image: theme-folder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename **Custom Templates** folder to **CRM**.

After renaming clear civicrm cache

Comment: Thanks!! It's works